# django add boolean to many-to-many relationship

Tags: django-models

In my application I am adding a simple message service that allows a user to send out a message to a subset of other users on the system:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Message(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s: %s' (self.sender.first_name,self.sender.last_name,self.timestamp)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('timestamp')
```

However, I would like to record if each user has read the message, so would need to add a boolean field to the table holding the many-to-many relationship.

Should I do this by explicitly adding another model and using ForeignKey() only, or is there a more 'django' way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, my googling power were weak, just found the right place in the documentation:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships